# import node to new document from old document runtime error VBA, XML

Tags: xml, vba

I’d like to take the fourth “Model” node (the one with the “Limited Company” as the customer) in one xml document and move it (in its entirety) to a new empty xml document.  I’ve seen a few threads about doing this type of thing in VB and Java but they didn’t quite help with exactly what I want to do (and none of them were using VBA).  They do however, suggest doing something like my last two lines of code but I can't get past an error in the last line.  How do I get this thing to append the node into the new document?  I'm sure I'm probably missing something very silly.  What is it?  Am I using importNode wrong?

My xmls.
fileName1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MyFile xmlns="urn:MyFile-schema">
    <Files>New</Files>
    <Source>Imported</Source>
    <Destination>Kia</Destination>
    <Auto>Sofia </Auto>
    <User>MMOUSE</User>
    <TimeStamp>2017-11-13T10:00:00</TimeStamp>
    <Model Source="Yes">
        <Customer>Jeff Mills</Customer>
        <CustomerCategory>Individual</CustomerCategory>
        <Vehicle>
            <VehicleName>Liona</VehicleName>
            <Door>
                <DoorColor>Brown</DoorColor>
            </Door>
            <Door>
                <DoorColor>Black</DoorColor>
            </Door>
        </Vehicle>
    </Model>
    <Model Source="Yes">
        <Customer>Jen Mills</Customer>
        <CustomerCategory>Individual</CustomerCategory>
        <Vehicle>
            <VehicleName>Cleo</VehicleName>
            <Door>
                <DoorColor>Brown</DoorColor>
            </Door>
            <Door>
                <DoorColor>Black</DoorColor>
            </Door>
        </Vehicle>
    </Model>
    <Model Source="Yes">
        <Customer>Dan Blackburn</Customer>
        <CustomerCategory>Individual</CustomerCategory>
        <Vehicle>
            <VehicleName>Christina</VehicleName>
            <Door>
                <DoorColor>Brown</DoorColor>
            </Door>
            <Door>
                <DoorColor>Black</DoorColor>
            </Door>
        </Vehicle>
    </Model>
    <Model Source="Yes">
        <Customer>Limited Company</Customer>
        <CustomerCategory>Corp</CustomerCategory>
        <Vehicle>
            <VehicleName>Jasmine</VehicleName>
            <Door>
                <DoorColor>red</DoorColor>
            </Door>
            <Door>
                <DoorColor>red</DoorColor>
            </Door>
        </Vehicle>
    </Model>
</MyFile>
```

fileName2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MyFile xmlns="urn:MyFile-schema">
    <Files>New</Files>
    <Source>Imported</Source>
    <Destination>Kia</Destination>
    <Auto>Sofia </Auto>
    <User>MMOUSE</User>
    <TimeStamp>2017-11-13T10:00:00</TimeStamp>
</MyFile>
```

And I would like fileName2 to look like this after the addition:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MyFile xmlns="urn:MyFile-schema">
    <Files>New</Files>
    <Source>Imported</Source>
    <Destination>Kia</Destination>
    <Auto>Sofia </Auto>
    <User>MMOUSE</User>
    <TimeStamp>2017-11-13T10:00:00</TimeStamp>
    <Model Source="Yes">
        <Customer>Limited Company</Customer>
        <CustomerCategory>Corp</CustomerCategory>
        <Vehicle>
            <VehicleName>Jasmine</VehicleName>
            <Door>
                <DoorColor>red</DoorColor>
            </Door>
            <Door>
                <DoorColor>red</DoorColor>
            </Door>
        </Vehicle>
    </Model>
</MyFile>
```

My code keeps throwing an error on the last line

> “Run-time error ‘438’: Object doesn’t support this property or method”

Here’s what I have:

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub MoveNode()

  'Declare Objects
  Dim oldDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument60                'Object for the oldDoc
  Dim newDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument60            'Object for the newDoc
  Dim newNode As IXMLDOMNode                    'for the new node

  'Initialize objects and Variables
  Set oldDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
  Set newDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
  oldDoc.validateOnParse = False
  newDoc.validateOnParse = False

  ‘some code to get filename and path from user and store as fileName1 and fileName2

  'Load the docs
  oldDoc.Load fileName1
  oldDoc.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:prefix='urn:MyFile-schema'"

  newDoc.Load fileName2
  newDoc.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:prefix='urn:MyFile-schema'"


  Set newNode = newDoc.importNode(oldDoc.SelectSingleNode("//prefix:Model[4]"), True)
  newDoc.SelectSingleNode("//prefix:MyFile").appendChild (newNode)
End Sub
```

Comment: Specifically which instruction is throwing error 438? Also, `xNode` being an object, you're passing whatever its *default member* value is by enclosing it in parentheses like this `(xNode)`. Drop the parentheses if you mean to pass the actual object reference as a parameter.

Comment: Declaring all your variables would also help. Right now `xNode` appears to be an undeclared variable, which means it's a `Variant` with some MSXML2 class subtype, probably an `IXMLDOMNode`. Anyway your last line is doing two things; split that up. See if `SelectSingleNode` works, and invoke `appendChild` on the result in another instruction. Much harder to debug a line of code that has multiple possible points of failure.

Comment: Apologies. I knew I would do that.  This has been edited for some content.  xNode should be newNode here.  I will edit this when I’m at a computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since @MathieuGuindon identified the main issue of wrapping parameter in parentheses where you can simply drop or assign to another object:

```vb
newDoc.SelectSingleNode("//prefix:MyFile").appendChild xNode
```

Alternatively, assign it as a function

```vb
Dim var As Variant

Set var = newDoc.SelectSingleNode("//prefix:MyFile").appendChild(xNode)
```

Consider the following best practices adjustments:

1. Include Error Handling that even raises the MSXML doc's `parseError`.
2. Modify your *Customer* search for a more direct one searching for *Limited Company* instead of node index, `[4]`, in case first XML can change ordering.
3. Include `.Save` to output modified *newDoc* to file.
4. Initialize all variables including *xNode* and possibly change variable name to identify operations as *newDoc* and *oldDoc* may be misleading since you are really adding.
5. Be sure to release `set` objects at end and possibly with a success message for user.

**VBA**

```vb
Sub MoveNode()
On Error GoTo ErrHandle
    'Declare Objects
    Dim srcfilename As String, addfilename As String, outputfilename As String
    Dim srcDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument60, addDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument60           
    Dim xNode As IXMLDOMNode, newNode As IXMLDOMNode

    'Initialize objects and Variables
    Set srcDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Set addDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    srcDoc.validateOnParse = False
    addDoc.validateOnParse = False

    'some code to get filenames from user
    srcfilename = "C:\Path\To\Source.xml"
    addfilename = "C:\Path\To\Add_Info.xml"
    outputfilename = "C:\Path\To\Output.xml"

    'Load the docs
    srcDoc.Load srcfilename
    srcDoc.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:prefix='urn:MyFile-schema'"

    addDoc.Load addfilename
    addDoc.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:prefix='urn:MyFile-schema'"

    'Parse docs
    Set xNode = srcDoc.importNode(addDoc.SelectSingleNode("//prefix:Model[prefix:Customer='Limited Company']"), True)
    srcDoc.SelectSingleNode("//prefix:MyFile").appendChild xNode

    srcDoc.Save outpfilename
    MsgBox "Successfully added node to original XML!", vbInformation
    GoTo ExitHandle

ExitHandle:
    Set srcDoc = Nothing: Set addDoc = Nothing: Set xNode = Nothing: Set newNode = Nothing
    Exit Sub

ErrHandle:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description, vbCritical
    Err.Raise srcDoc.parseError.ErrorCode, , srcDoc.parseError.reason
    Resume ExitHandle
End Sub
```

Comment: I really appreciate the comments!  Food for thought for me because there are things you mention that I do not have.  There are a couple things I do, I just have edited them out for simplicity sake (specifically 3,4 and 5 without a success message but I like that, I will include one).  Also, I actually have an index pointing to the model node because the bigger picture is another thread I started a while back.  I have an xml file with this structure with upwards of 20k “model” nodes and I need to randomly select 500 of them and place them in a new file.  I was originally going to delete to 500.

Comment: Got it. For larger project, really then look into XSLT script where you can pass parameters from VBA into it (very much like passing params from app layer to SQL queries) for that random node index split.

Comment: I think you actually answered on that one too....this is much better than what I had before and now all I have to do is add a for loop to 500.  It will work way way faster than deleting like I had.

Answer (score 1):

Because I would be remiss to pass up the chance, consider also [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/), the transformation language designed to manipulate XML files. The [MSXML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms759204(v=vs.85).aspx) library can run XSLT 1.0 scripts and XSLT maintains the `document()` function and so can parse across XML files. Be sure to place both *source* and *add info* documents in same folder.

**XSLT** *(save below as .xsl file, a special .xml file)*

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                              xmlns:doc="urn:MyFile-schema" >
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="doc:MyFile">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
        <xsl:copy-of select="document('Add_Info.xml')/doc:MyFile
                             /doc:Model[doc:Customer='Limited Company']" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**VBA**

```vb
Sub XSLTransform()
On Error GoTo ErrHandle
    Dim xmldoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument, xslDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument, newDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument

    ' LOAD XML AND XSL FILES
    xmlDoc.async = False
    xmldoc.Load "C:\Path\To\Source.xml"

    xslDoc.async = False
    xslDoc.Load "C:\Path\To\XSLT_Script.xsl"

    ' TRANSFORM XML
    xmldoc.transformNodeToObject xslDoc, newDoc
    newDoc.Save "C:\Path\To\Output.xml"

    MsgBox "Successfully transformed XML!", vbInformation
    GoTo ExitHandle

ExitHandle:
    Set xmldoc = Nothing: Set xslDoc = Nothing: Set newDoc = Nothing
    Exit Sub

ErrHandle:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description, vbCritical
    Err.Raise xslDoc.parseError.ErrorCode, , xslDoc.parseError.reason
    Resume ExitHandle

End Sub
```

The beauty too of XSLT is that it is portable and does not need MSXML to run it. Hence, even Java or Python or PHP can run it to render same output! You can also run other manipulations such as adding other nodes, changing node names, text values, etc. all in same script.

Comment: These are all great!  Thanks so much!  I’m not at a computer at the moment but will be trying this as soon as I get a chance and mark a solution if they work.  Everything I’ve been doing is largely self taught over the past couple years in my free time.  I haven’t had the time to learn much XSLT but I plan on it.  Any recommendations for resources???

Comment: Like you, I self-taught myself. Look up [XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt/info) tutorials or book at local library! For me, I learn by doing (trial/error). So try modifying a simple XML in various ways and go to more complex items.